# ResourceAccessException when trying to execute a post service

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am getting this exception
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException
I/O error on POST request for \"http://host.docker.internal:8073/user-management/users/login\": Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect",
My code looks like this

```
@Resource(name="restTemp")
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

String url = "user-management/users/login";
        //String fullUrl = "https://localhost:8073/user-management/users/login";
        InstanceInfo instance = eurekaClient.getNextServerFromEureka("user-management", false);
        LoginRequest user =  restTemplate.postForObject(instance.getHomePageUrl()+url, loginRequest, LoginRequest.class);
```

Also I dont understand why instance.getHomePageUrl() generates a internal docker url . what could be the reason behind this docker desktop is running. 
I need help in resolving this exception.According to what I could find this exception occurs when we are trying to access a third party url

Comment: Something like this? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/432

Comment: The exception clearly states that, the remote host is not working. Because of that connection is not able to established. Can you try to access the same from outside

Comment: its a connection problem.try to ping the server and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try increasing the context timeout for request sent by RestTemplate